# using awk command to compare the two files and print all the columns then missing display as NA

Tags: text-processing, awk, join

File 1:

```
123, 234
345, 789
678, 900
```

File 2

```
123, abc
345, dnc
```

Desired output (all columns in file1 and missing value in file two as NA):

```
123,234,abc
345,789,dnc
678,900,NA
```

Answer (score 3):

It's easier if you use [join](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/join.html):

```
$ join -t, -a 1 -a 2 -j 1 -e ' NA' -o auto file1 file2
123, 234, abc
345, 789, dnc
678, 900, NA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F ", ?" -v OFS=, 'FNR == NR { a[$1]=$2;next; };
  { if ($1 in a) print $1,$2,a[$1]; else print $1,$2,"NA"; }' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 0):

awk

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=""}NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;};NR>FNR{if($1 in a){print $0,", ",a[$1];}else{print $0,", NA";}}' file2 file1 > tmp
```

the output will be stored in tmp,as you asked to update from file3

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=""}NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;};NR>FNR{if($1 in a){print $0,", ",a[$1];}else{print $0,", NA";}}' file3 tmp
```

output:

```
123, 234, abc, 2014/10/20
345, 789, dnc, NA
678, 900, NA, 2013/02/30
```