# Need to compare the two files and print all the columns then missing display as NA, then join another file

Tags: text-processing, awk, scripting, join

File 1:

```
123, 234
345, 789
678, 900
```

File 2

```
123, abc
345, dnc
```

output (all columns in file1 and missing value in file two as NA):

```
123,234,abc
345,789,dnc
678,900,NA
```

Output file 
 add with another file

File 3

```
123, 2014/10/20
678, 2013/02/30
```

Output file

```
123,234,abc,2014/10/20
345,789,dnc,NA
678,900,NA,2013/02/30
```

There are such 10 files which I need to add to the 1st file

Comment: I answered this in your previous post check it, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165827/using-awk-command-to-compare-the-two-files-and-print-all-the-columns-then-missin

Answer (score 2):

If you have many input files and you have to repeat procedure one way to simplify this task is to define a function:

```
myjoin () {
join -t, -a 1 -a 2 -j 1 -e ' NA' -o auto $1 $2 ; }
```

And then invoke it using proces substitution `<()` as

```
myjoin <(myjoin file1 file2) file3
```

The result:

```
123, 234, abc, 2014/10/20
345, 789, dnc, NA
678, 900, NA, 2013/02/30
```

I have used here [cuonglm answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/165829/80886) from your previous question with join, you can of course use this method with any other 'single' solution.